# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified on a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have encountered an TNS error when access one of the table on external database. But when I tried to access on other table through the same external db link it does not have any error.

What might be the cause of it?

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename@db;
```

Error:

```
12154. 00000 -  "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"
*Cause:    A connection to a database or other service was requested using
           a connect identifier, and the connect identifier specified could not
           be resolved into a connect descriptor using one of the naming methods
           configured. For example, if the type of connect identifier used was a
           net service name then the net service name could not be found in a
           naming method repository, or the repository could not be
           located or reached.
*Action:   
           - If you are using local naming (TNSNAMES.ORA file):
           - Make sure that "TNSNAMES" is listed as one of the values of the
           NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile
           (SQLNET.ORA)
           - Verify that a TNSNAMES.ORA file exists and is in the proper
           directory and is accessible.
           - Check that the net service name used as the connect identifier
           exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.
           - Make sure there are no syntax errors anywhere in the TNSNAMES.ORA
           file.  Look for unmatched parentheses or stray characters. Errors
           in a TNSNAMES.ORA file may make it unusable.
           - If you are using directory naming:
           - Verify that "LDAP" is listed as one of the values of the
           NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile
           (SQLNET.ORA).
           - Verify that the LDAP directory server is up and that it is
           accessible.
           - Verify that the net service name or database name used as the
           connect identifier is configured in the directory.
           - Verify that the default context being used is correct by
           specifying a fully qualified net service name or a full LDAP DN
           as the connect identifier
           - If you are using easy connect naming:
           - Verify that "EZCONNECT" is listed as one of the values of the
           NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile
           (SQLNET.ORA).
           - Make sure the host, port and service name specified
           are correct.
           - Try enclosing the connect identifier in quote marks.
Error at Line: 2 Column: 6
```

Comment: How do you connect to the remote database? The issue is with your connection.. And not the query. Make sure the DB link uses the connection string that is available in the TNSNAMES.ora

Comment: You'll need to examine the link to figure out the problem. Also, this question would be better, I think, on dba.stackexchange.com. Best of luck.

Comment: Can you give more details about the table you are trying to access

Comment: Be aware that it is the TNSNAMES.ORA seen by the database service that matters. If the database on which you run the query is not your workstation but e.g. some linux server, then "DB" needs to be defined in the TNSNAMES.ORA of the linux Oracle server installation. And even if it is your own local workstation database it will still have its own TNSNAMES.ORA apart from that of the Oracle client installation.

Comment: It does not make sense though that it works for one table but not for another. Can you consistently reproduce that behavior? Do you run out of the same local schema in both cases?

Comment: Who owns the table in question on the remote database? Also, is that table long existing? Show us the real code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First from the host where your Oracle instance is located try to tnsping the oracle instance that is used in your db_link configuration.

```
tnsping SID/TNS Alias
```

If you get someting like

```
TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

you need to check you tnsnames.ora file and see if you have an tns alias pointing to database instance where the tablename@db is located.

- if there is no entry add one and test again.
- also make sure no domain is required, for this you need to
  validate/check your sqlnet.ora located in your TNS_ADMIN location.
- one other thing if you are on windows make sure that you are using
  the correct client, maybe some KEYS are baddly configured in your
  REGEDIT
- -after tnsping is solved test your db_link:

  select * from global_name@db_link;

Your database name should come up! 
I hope this was helpfull